# How do I keep my program asking me info until I tell him to stop?

Tags: c

Im making a calculator with A LOT of functions, Im not nearly done with the functions. But I thought, I want the program active after returning me the value I asked for. My logic was to put it into a while loop, but clearly my idea and how I put it are not equal. Or maybe my logic doesnt work in this case. Anyway, imagine I ask the program how much its 2+2 and it returns me 4. Done, but I want it to ask me again for another operation, how can I do that?
Im really new with this stuff, so thanks for the help.

To resume the code below. I ask for a value, then scan it, then ask for a operator, then I ask wether if the user want to continue or not, if he says yes thats the condition for the loop ---> while(condition != 'yes' );{
And if not, just end the program. And I putted the operations inside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    double sinus;
    int op;

    printf(" What function do you want to use? \n \n --------------------------------------- \n");
    printf(" BASIC OPERATIONS --> type 1 \n --------------------------------------- \n");
    printf(" TRIGONOMETRIC FUNCTIONS \n sin --> type 2 \n cos --> type 3 \n tan --> type 4 \n arcsin --> type 5 \n arccos --> type 6 \n arctan --> type 7 \n --------------------------------------- \n");

    scanf("%d", &op);
    char condition[5];

    printf("Stop? Type: yes or no");
    scanf("%s", &condition);

    while(condition != 'yes' );{

    if (op == 1) {

        double val1;
        char op1;
        double val2;

        printf("Please type a number: \n" );
        scanf("%lf", &val1);

        printf("Please type an operator: \n" );
        scanf(" %c", &op1);

        printf("Please type another number: \n" );
        scanf("%lf", &val2);

        if (op1 == '+') {
            printf("%f \n", val1 + val2);
        }
        if (op1 == '-') {
            printf("%f \n", val1 - val2);
        }
        if (op1 == '*') {
            printf("%f \n", val1 * val2);
        }
        if (op1 == '/') {
            printf("%f \n", val1 / val2);
        }

    }

    else if (op == 2) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of sin(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", sin(arg));
    }

    else if (op == 3) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of cos(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", cos(arg));
    }

    else if (op == 4) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of tan(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", tan(arg));
    }

    else if (op == 5) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of arcsin(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", asin(arg));
    }

    else if (op == 6) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of arccos(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", acos(arg));
    }

    else if (op == 7) {
        double arg;
        printf("Please type the argument of arctan(x) \n");
        scanf("%lf", &arg);
        printf("The value is %f", atan(arg));
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", 0);
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for too many to read:((( Im not experienced with forums.

Comment: That's not how you compare strings in C. Lookup `strcmp`. Also, you don't update `condition` inside the loop

Comment: explore [do while](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop)

Comment: Further to John3136's comment. You declare characters inside single quotes and strings of characters inside double-quotes. I.e `"yes"` (3 characters and a null-terminator) and not `'yes'`(invalid syntax) also `'a'`(a single character, a) and not `"a"` (the character a and a null-terminator)

Comment: Beside the erroneous comparison of the strings, you have a straying semicolon between `while (...)` and its supposed statement block. This forms an empty loop body.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will give you an idea how things can be repeated based on input.

check how `strcmp` is done,that way you are doing is wrong.

Also consider using [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) for handling multiple cases of input and their operations.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> // isspace

int main() {
   char choice[] = "Yes";
   
   do{
        int i = 0;
        
        /** 
         * implement all you want here
        */
        
        printf("Enter Yes to repeat, to exit enter any other non blank string\n");
        while(isspace(choice[i] = getchar()));
        while((choice[++i] = getchar()) != '\n');
        choice[i] = '\0';
        printf("choice = %s, i = %d\n", choice, i);
       
   }while(!strcmp(choice,"Yes") );
   return 0;
}
```